# How to set Opacity to a selected Graphic in ESRI map

Tags: esri-maps, arcgis-android-api

In my android app I am adding a picture marker symbol on [ESRI map](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/10-2/guide/develop-your-first-map-app.htm) using [PictureMarkerSymbol](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/symbology/PictureMarkerSymbol.html) class(using Kotlin) like:

```
val markerSymbol = PictureMarkerSymbol.createAsync(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context!!, icon) as BitmapDrawable?).get()
```

Here am adding multiple markers on map by setting default opacity of symbol and adding it to overlay like:

```
        markerSymbol.opacity = 0.3f
        //add a new graphic as marker point
        val markerGraphicPoint = Point(activeCall.lang, activeCall.lat, spatialReference)
        val graphic = Graphic(markerGraphicPoint, markerSymbol)

        graphicsOverlay.graphics.add(graphic)
```

Now I want to set the opacity to a selected graphic(Anyway I am getting the selected graphic symbol from an array). I can get the symbol from selected graphic like:

```
selectedGraphic?.symbol
```

I want to set opacity to selected symbol something like:

```
selectedGraphic?.symbol = 1.0f // Need this one
```

But how to set the opacity to it, there is no setOpacity in this symbol class

OR how to get the PictureMarkerSymbol from the selected Graphic.?

I tried by cast it to `PictureMarkerSymbol` this way:

```
selectedMarker?.symbol as PictureMarkerSymbol
```

but here I am getting class cast exception

Also tried:

```
val markerGraphicsOverlay = selectedMarker?.graphicsOverlay
markerGraphicsOverlay?.opacity = 0.1f
```

but same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast Symbol to `PictureMarkerSymbol`

```
if (selectedGraphic!= null && selectedGraphic?.symbol != null) {
    val pictureMarkerSymbol = selectedGraphic?.symbol as PictureMarkerSymbol
}
```